# Are classes methods created individually for instances?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to know whether in ActionScript 3 there's a way to share a same function (method) between the instances of a class definition, only referencing the same function everytime... i.e., this example should log `true`, but logged `false` (note: I'd want this to reduce duplicating functions).

```
class A {
    function f() {}
}

trace(
    (new A).f === (new A).f
)
```

An ActionScript 3 language specification appears to say that a `prototype` attribute exists, but not implemented. I've understood that individual classes have a prototype object. I've specially found a prototype property (probably inherited from `Class`/`Object`) and wonder if classes use meta functions in order to be constructed (since their type is "object"... when I test with typeof: `trace(typeof A, typeof Class, typeof Object)`).

My last try:

```
class A {}

A.prototype.f = function() {}

trace(
      (new A).f === (new A).f
)
```

It says that `f` doesn't exist. I could define this class as a function instead (in order to move methods to the prototype object):

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.f = function() {}
```

, but in this way I can't control access of instance members.

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question with `new A().f === new A().f` being `false`. But: `I'd want this to reduce duplicating functions` -- *why* do you want to reduce "duplicating functions" in this way? Do you think it would be a performance optimization? Does it solve some problem you're having, like comparing equality of two objects?

Comment: @Aaron *why do you want to reduce "duplicating functions" in this way?* , exactly to get performance optimization. *Does it solve some problem you're having, like comparing equality of two objects?*, not this comparision, but to reduce functions created by each instance. If I were going to construct a class with various methods in a lot of times, then it could be slow, couldn't it?

Comment: @Aaron What I'm trying to mean is that it's not neccessary to create each instance method of a class definition for each instance, it could just be on the class prototype and be shared among the object of instances. If `new A().f === new A().f` gave me `false`, then it simply means that these two function references are pointing to different functions (this means that the method might be getting binded or yes, re-created).

Comment: @handoncloud Class methods are bind to class instances and that's exactly why they output false when you == compare  method references. When you create a new instance of a class the class methods are not "duplicated" or copied or whatever. Please do not overthink it. If you happen encounter a specific problem of your code running too slow, optimize the code, there always are plenty of ways.

Comment: @Organis No, I don't have any code running slow. I'm not projecting anything yet. And I think it's a bad idea to bind methods

Comment: @handoncloud Well, you can report your thoughts to Adobe Flash team. As of now, what you say reads (no offense) "I have a gut feeling with no substantial proof that Flash Player team failed to solve some basic efficiency problem at the lower level so I am totally going to fix it at the higher level."

Comment: @Organis No, I won't fix it at the higher level. Just FYI I'm not gonna use the actual AS3 implementations, I was just planning to do an implementation, but I'm starting to give up after I've noticed that;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS3 uses [Bound methods](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa5) to ensure that inside your functions, `this` always points to original instance object by default.

Imagine that you pass a function `f` of an instance `a` to some other object `b`. When then object `b` calls function `f`, the  `this` name still points to `a` inside scope of the function - this reference has to be store somewhere.

Well, you could assign function to static property of your class:

```
package adnss.projects.evTest 
{

    public class A {

        private var x:Number = 5;
        private var _y:Number = 0;

        public function A(){}

        static public const f = function (p:Number):Number {
            this._y = p;
            return this.x*p;        
        }

        public function get y():Number { return _y; }
    }
}
```

And then have access to private properties of the instance of `A` in that static function by explicitly using `this`:

```
var instance:A = new A();
trace("return:", A.f.call(instance, 3)); //return: 15
trace("instace:", instance.y); //instance: 3
```

But that is kind of tricky for possible benefits (if any).

And about prototypes. You basically don't use them in AS3. Is't there like a souvenir :) - [read this for more info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa3)